# Why I cant run jar file in IntelliJ via Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, flyway

I have a Gradle project in IntelliJ and I've added a jar file to the project library ( a fly-way plugin).

When running the build i'm getting an error because it's trying to execute java 
but from a directory where it doesn't exist.

While Java home is set as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\` 
it's trying to locate it in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java`.

Why is that? Everything in IntelliJ settings looks correct.

Must add that I'm new to these applications.

Comment: Has gradle in intellij it's own settings? Are you running gradle from a terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it !
It was under External Libraries the java directory there was the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Please check and compare the Java setting in intellij with the one in your operating system.

You can run this in a terminal

```
> java -version
```

That should show you your systems java version.

Gradle also uses a gradle.properties file in your project root which can contain further Gradle specific settings.